# MySQL Workbench: Error Code: 1222. The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-workbench, error-code

I am using MySQL Workbench for an assignment and I got the "ERROR CODE 1222: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

I am kind of new to SQL and I can not figure out where my issue is.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION discount_price(itemId INT) RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE itemPrice DECIMAL(10,2);
 DECLARE discount DECIMAL(10,2);

 SELECT product_name, list_price, discount_percent INTO itemPrice, discount
 FROM products
 WHERE product_id = itemId;

 RETURN itemPrice - (itemPrice * discount);
END //

DELIMITER ;

-- Test the stored function
SELECT discount_price(1) AS discounted_price;
```

Grateful for any help, Thank you!

Comment: You're SELECTing three columns into two variables, which clearly can't work. Did you read the words in the error message? It tells you **exactly** what the problem is with your code. The error message isn't there just to fill up space on your screen. Did you try reading the MySQL documentation about SELECT...INTO? It doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: Thank you Ken, your very aggressive teaching style is greatly appreciated. You must be very happy with your life to be so willing to help a newbie out. I tried making select have only two columns, however it still threw the error. I was following the formatting given for me to do this assignment and figured I should post it with the formatting style the book was showing me. Thank you again for revitalizing my hope in humanity.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want one value back from the function, a "discounted price", then you need to do a calculation inside the function, and you must use the same number of variables as the number of columns specified in the select clause:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION fnDiscountPrice (p_itemId INT)
RETURNS DECIMAL(10, 2) READS SQL DATA DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN
    -- Declare variables to hold the item price and discount
    DECLARE v_itemPrice DECIMAL(10, 2);
    DECLARE v_discount DECIMAL(10, 2);

    -- Select the item price and discount from the products table
    SELECT list_price, discount_percent
    INTO v_itemPrice, v_discount
    FROM products
    WHERE product_id = p_itemId;

    -- Calculate the discounted price and return it
    RETURN v_itemPrice - (v_itemPrice * v_discount);
END //

DELIMITER;
```

Note there are a number of assumptions here about the data, and there is no error handling (which should be introduced) e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnDiscountPrice(p_itemId INT) RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  -- Declare variables to hold the item price and discount
  DECLARE v_itemPrice DECIMAL(10,2);
  DECLARE v_discount DECIMAL(10,2);

  -- Select the item price and discount from the products table
  SELECT list_price, discount_percent INTO v_itemPrice, v_discount
  FROM products
  WHERE product_id = p_itemId
  -- force the query to return only a single row
  LIMIT 1;

  -- Check if the discount is NULL and return the list price in that case
  IF v_discount IS NULL THEN
    RETURN v_itemPrice;
  ELSE
    -- Calculate the discounted price and return it
    RETURN v_itemPrice - (v_itemPrice * v_discount);
  END IF;

  -- Exception handler to catch any errors that occur during the execution of the function
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    RETURN -1; -- Return a custom error code or message
  END;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you, this was super helpful and informative!